# What is the alternative to the moment.locales() in dayJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs, locale, dayjs

**MomentJS** has a function to return all the locales loaded. Couldn't find the similar in **DayJS**. is there any way to achieve the same in **DayJS**

ref: https://runkit.com/embed/nwd9wgdxbm9i